# How write method which connects to layoutAboutToBeChanged/layoutChanged signal

Tags: c++, qt

I have my custom `QSortFilterProxyModel` which overrides `filterAcceptRow` and `lessThan` methods. `filterAcceptRow` method works nice, but when I try using sort and filter together, the filter breaks. I think this is because the proxy model is not notified about sorting.
In `Qt` sources I read that `QListWidget::sort` method emits `layoutAboutToBeChanged` before sort, `layoutChanged` and nothing more.

In `Qt` doc i read:

> Subclasses should update any persistent model indexes after emitting layoutAboutToBeChanged().

But how I should do it? Can you write example?

Comment: What about the Qt doc. example? [Custom Sort/Filter Model Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-customsortfiltermodel-example.html). Btw. I didn't find any call of `layoutAboutToBeChanged` or `layoutChange` there. May be, the calls of [`QSortFilterProxyModel::invalidateFilter()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#invalidateFilter) are the missing piece?

Comment: @Scheff no. I looking for way for notify model when sortiong. I read this exapmle. It haven't sorting